# login displaying wrong username and password

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I got this login form, it is then verified by the users.php file, but even tough the username and the password are on the database, it says the password is wrong. The database is working correctly and it's connected to the page.

Login form:

```
     <?php


require_once('/funcoes/Users.php');
if( !empty($_POST)){


    try{
        $users = new OOP_Users();
        $result = $users->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        if ( $result == 'ok'){

        }
        else{
            echo "Username/Password erradas!!"; 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Authentication error!";
    }
}   
    else{
        session_start();
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body><?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    ?>  
         <form name="Formulario_Login" action="#" method="POST"/> 
         <table>
         <tr>
         <td> Username </td><td><input name="username" type="text" <span style="font-size: 15px;" ></input></td></tr>
         <tr>
         <td> Password </td><td><input name="password" type="password" <span style="font-size: 15px;"></input></td></tr></tr>

         <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
         </table>
         <?php

    }
    else{

        echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'] . "! <br>".'<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
        echo '<br><a href="editarUser.php">Alterar perfil</a>';
        echo '<br><a href="apagarUser.php">Apagar conta</a>';
    }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the users.php i got this function

Users.php:

```
public function login($username, $password){


    $result = $this->_myDB->performQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username' = '$username' AND 'password' = '$password'");


    if ( $result->num_rows != 1 ){
        return ('Authentication error');
    }
    else{
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            return('ok');


    }

}
```

Even tough i have the username "ines" and the password "ines123" on the database, every time i try to login i got the error: "Authentication error!"

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: look at the quotes around username in the query

Comment: I corrected the quotes on the users.php file, now the query is: "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND 'password' = '$password'"  but now i got the message ""Username/Password erradas!!"" that is on the login.php file when verifying the fields

Comment: `'password' = '$password'` is the same as saying `'password' = 'ines123'` (which is a string compare between two terms). By putting the quotes around the `password` column name, you're making it a term, not a column name. You can use ticks like ` (think accent) but, unless it's a reserved word or has special characters (like a space) in the column name, you don't need anything around the column name.